# Can't get an auto_incremented field after save in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a table which contains an auto_increment field "autoValue" which is not the primary key or a part of it.

```
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Integer autoValue;
    ....
}
```

When I save my object (method save()) the row is inserted in the database and the auto_increment is successfully done. However if I try to get the value of autoValue I get Null value.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.setId("newStringId");
session.save(obj);
obj.getAutoValue();// <= this returns null
```

Could someone tell where is the problem and how to process to retrieve the value of autoValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try refreshing the Hibernate session to sync your object with the new state of the database, which should reflect the auto generated value.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.setId("newStringId");
session.save(obj);
session.flush();
session.refresh(obj);
obj.getAutoValue();   // should have the auto generated value
```

From the Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-loading):

> It is possible to re-load an object and all its collections at any time, using the refresh() method. This is useful when database triggers are used to initialize some of the properties of the object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried it but it doesn't work and also returns Null

Comment: Actually, it does work I forgot in my code to call refresh(obj) after calling flush(). Thank you so much and I think that the question was answered.